# QWebEngineView let's stylesheet border disappear

Tags: python, qt, pyside2, qwebengineview

Faced a strange issue with QWebEngineView: I have a qt ui file with a style sheet in it, which has a border defined. When loaded in python it looks as it should. The file holds a frame in it. As soon as I add a QWebEngineView to the frame, the border of the main widget disappears on top, right and bottom. On the left side it's still there. Anyone knows that issue?

Thats my code:

```
class ViewWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ViewWindow, self).__init__()
        loader = QUiLoader()
        file = QFile(abspath("ui/view.ui"))
        file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
        self.view_screen = loader.load(file, self)
        file.close()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.Window | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.browser=QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("https://www.google.at"))
        self.layout.addWidget(self.browser)
        self.browser.hide()
        self.view_screen.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.browser.show)
        self.view_screen.frame.setLayout(self.layout)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
view = ViewWindow()
view.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks.

Comment: share `view.ui`

Comment: [link](http://kutschera.co.at/temp/view.ui)

Comment: What border do you mean? I get the following: https://imgur.com/a/yHxcGIx

Comment: You could show a picture of what you get to understand you better, one without the QWebEngineView that shows the border and the other with the QWebEngineView.

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/yVJT31N) with QWebEngineView - [link](https://imgur.com/evaX00i) without QWebEngineView. Changed the color to red for better visability.

Comment: I do not see the red border. https://imgur.com/a/00Qcus1

Comment: Sorry, i didn't upload the changed ui file, but now i have.

Comment: In Linux it works correctly: https://imgur.com/a/I7WANkz, 
What is your OS?

Comment: Thanks fot testing. Win 7 Professional 64-bit. What version of Qt do you use?

Comment: I'm going to try on my virtual machine, I'm using PySide2 5.11

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue with my pc. Tried on another windows 7 machine and it works like a charm.

Thanks